# Получение списка бустов telegram канала

Tags: telegram-bot

В телеграмм канале есть функция буст, которая дает возможность каналу публиковать истории.
Кто-нибудь знает как можно получить список пользователей забустивших канал?

Первая идея была найти либу по типу telethon, но этого я не смог сделать, тк такой функции там нет, второй способ это парсить данные с эмулятора android, что я и удачно реализовал, но скорость выполнения безумно большая. Можно было бы получать данные через rest, но проблема в том, что в веб версии нет статистики бустов
Возможно есть какие то библиотеки или другие пути решения?